# Android actionbar refresh when rotating and multi-pane

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an activity the same as the following image:

[image: Handset vs Tablet]

FragmentA is a listview and has a SearchWidget as menu-item (which is not displayed on old devices, only API11 and above). 
FragmentB is a detail view and has several menu-items.

When ActivityA runs on a tablet, the menu-items of FragmentA + FragmentB are visible in the actionbar. This is correct and works perfect.

Now on a Nexus 7 I want a mix of those:

- In portrait only use the handset layout
- When I rotate the device, the tablet layout is loaded

The only thing which I can't seem to get working is the actionbar. When I rotate the device from landscape mode (tablet view) back to portrait (handset view), still the actionbar shows the menu-items of FragmentA + FragmentB.

I've tried calling the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` from `onResume()` in both ActivityA as FragmentA, but without luck.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due activity re-creation process.

When screen is rotated your activity is destroyed (by default).
But before it is destroyed it saves state including states of all currently active fragments.
Later, when activity is creating after orientation change it restores saved state (with both fragments). As details fragment restores it appends menu items.

You can check this by adding log statements or using debugger in `onCreateView` of `DetailsFragment`.

If it's your case then you have next solutions:

1. Suppress saving state (must be avoided if DetailsFragment should keep track of last displayed item or something similar) by removing this fragment before activity save its state.
2. Suppress any initialization of DetailsFragment if it will not be displayed. Activity should give answer about visibility.
3. Your variant? I think two approaches above isn't good enough...

Sorry if my answer didn't help you at all

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
In Activity A try find Fragment B and set setHasOptionsMenu(mTwoPane)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_document_list);

    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_DETAIL);

    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_detail)){
        mTwoPane = true;

        ....

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(mTwoPane);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```